# OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am used this function to execute stored procedure,

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Test]
     (@d1 DATE,
      @d2 DATE, 
      @nd VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
        (WITH AllDates AS
         (
             SELECT @d1 AS DateOf
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATEADD (DAY, 1, DateOf­)
             FROM AllDates
             WHERE DateOf < @d2
         )
         SELECT COUNT() SumOfDays
         FROM AllDates
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM STRING_SPLIT(@nd,' ')
                       WHERE DATENAME(weekday,dat­eof) = value) 
                       OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
                      )
```

The result is supposed to know how many of 'Monday Tuesday Saturday' are  between Date1 And Date 2

n.b i need to add `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` in the function but it's not working ,

But I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.

Comment: Have you considered creating a calendar table instead? With 1 row per day, 20 years worth of data is less than 10000 rows which makes it a tiny table, and it makes not just this function but many others trivial.

Comment: Functions are not stored procedures, btw.

Comment: Query hints have to be specified on the outermost query, e.g. here it would have to be on the query that consumes your function - hence my suggestion to avoid recursion entirely instead.

Comment: Why not use a tally, not a rCTE? Then you have no recursion, and thus can't have the problem of reaching the maximum recursion number if `OPTION` is omitted. They're also *far* faster than an rCTE as well.

Comment: This looks familiar

Answer (score 1):

OPTION clause can be used only at the statement level. So you cannot use it within a query expression inside view definitions or inline TVFs etc. The only way to use it in your case is to create the TVF without the OPTION clause and specify it in the query that uses the TVF. We have a bug that tracks request for allowing use of OPTION clause inside any query expression (for example, if exists() or CTE or view).

Here is the that that you can visit to refer more: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7c7d5fea-38ad-4bc5-9038-a157e640561f/using-option-clause-within-create-function-statement-for-inline-table-functions?forum=transactsql

So in your example, you must specify the OPTION when you call your function:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Test](@d1 DATE, @d2 DATE, @nd VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
WITH AllDates AS
(
SELECT @d1 AS DateOf
UNION ALL
SELECT DateAdd(day,1,DateOf­)
FROM AllDates
WHERE DateOf<@d2
)
select COUNT() SumOfDays
FROM AllDates
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@nd,' ')
WHERE DATENAME(weekday,dat­eof) = value) 
)
```

Now you can use Option at SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Test] ( @d1 , @d2, @nd ) OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Hope to help, my friend :))

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer to stop the recursion error would be to get rid of the recursion. If there's no recursion then there's no problem!

This is very simple to do as well, as you simply use a tally instead. This also has a speed benefit, as a Tally is (significantly) faster than a rCTE. I use an inline tally for this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test (@D1 date, @D2 date, @nd varchar(100)) --There's no need for MAX
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (WITH N AS(
            SELECT N
            FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
        Tally AS(
            SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@D1,@D2)) --It appears you don't include the last day in your logic
                                                      --If it should, add +1 to the DATEDIFF value
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
            FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5), --More than enough rows
        Dates AS(
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @D1) AS D
            FROM Tally T)
        SELECT COUNT(D.D) AS SumOfDays
        FROM Dates D
        WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM STRING_SPLIT(@nd,' ')
                     WHERE DATENAME(weekday,D.D) = value))
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test('20000101','20200101','Sunday Saturday');
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.Test;
```

I change the length of `@nd` as there's no need for it to be a `MAX`. The string `'Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday'` is only 56 characters long, so a `varchar(100)` is more than enough. You may, however, want to use an `nvarchar`, to ensure this function works for other languages; as a character may end up being lost.

Answer (score 0):

The option is associated with the outermost `select`:

```
RETURN (
    WITH AllDates AS(
          SELECT @d1 AS DateOf
          UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD (DAY, 1, DateOf­)
          FROM AllDates
          WHERE DateOf < @d2
        )
     SELECT COUNT() SumOfDays
     FROM AllDates
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM STRING_SPLIT(@nd,' ')
                   WHERE DATENAME(weekday,dat­eof) = value) 
                  )
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
    )
```